# Get directly a layer with all features from OUTPUT <OutputVector> in processing.runalg() results?

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, qgis-processing

I'm using `Processing` algorithm with PyQgis, and I'm asking how can I directly get a layer from the `OUTPUT <OutputVector>` value returned by the `qgis:fixeddistancebuffer` algorithm.

```py
print processing.alghelp("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer")
ALGORITHM: Fixed distance buffer
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    DISTANCE <ParameterNumber>
    SEGMENTS <ParameterNumber>
    DISSOLVE <ParameterBoolean>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

I try to compute multiple radius on multiple feature stored in my vlayer shapefile.

```py
from qgis.core import *

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("my_shapes.shp", "blabla", "ogr")

poly_output_file="test_poly.shp"

radius = [0.2, 0.5]
for r in radius:
    processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", vlayer , r, 99, False, poly_output_file + "_%s" % r )
```

Is there a more direct way to get all features generated into one layer, without creating multiple `poly_output_file_r.shp` ?

Error with 2.18 :

```py
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 196, in qgis_excepthook
    showException(type, value, tb, None, messagebar=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 107, in showException
    open_stack_dialog(type, value, tb, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 142, in open_stack_dialog
    iface.messageBar().popWidget()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'messageBar'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reyman/Projets/cours/exercice/pyQgis/generateBufferIsland.py", line 73, in <module>
    get_output= general.getObject(buff_res['OUTPUT']) # you can use any name intead of get_output
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getObject'
```

Comment: I edit my question because i found answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write the result directly to the disk, you can manage the output layer by adding a name to your algorithm and then by setting `None` as output.

For example, if you change this code block:

```
for r in radius:
    processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", vlayer , r, 99, False, poly_output_file + "_%s" % r )
```

to this one (for example):

```
for r in radius:
    buff_res = processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", vlayer , r, 99, False, None ) # you can use any name instead of buff_res

get_output= processing.getObject(buff_res['OUTPUT']) # you can use any name intead of get_output
```

you will able to use it for your needs.

For example, if you want to iterate over the resulting features, you will write:

```
for feat in get_output.getFeatures():
    # some stuff
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) One little mistake, its `Processing.getObject(...)`

Comment: Thanks, you was right in that case but, since with the libraries provided before there was another error in `QgsVectorLayer`, I preferred changing the original code. Now it should be work.

Comment: Hum, i try this code with 2.18 version of Qgis and don't work again, it's weird :s

Comment: I tested it on QGIS 2.18.1: what is the error you get?

Comment: Hum, i remove Processing by processing and i retry

Comment: If you want to buffer multiple features from the same layer, this is not what you asked here for (i.e. how to access to an output from a processing algorithm). Please create a new question.

Comment: I update my question with error message with 2.18

Comment: You need to write `processing` instead of `general` (see carefully my answer).

Comment: I use general and not processing because my import is `from processing.tools import general` So i need to import processing now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49650/discussion-between-howtoinqgis-and-reyman64).